# How to draw mapline with highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I have a highcharts map with two mappoints. You can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/na85bqqp/1/.

The follwoing data format doesn't seem to work for maplines.

```
        data: [{
          name: 'London',
          lat: 42.4072,
          lon: -71.3824,
        }, 
        {
          name: 'Wisconsin',
          lat: 43.7844,
          lon: -88.7879,
        }]
```

I want these two points connected. How can I achieve this? Highcharts documentation for mapline isn't proper, so I can't figure out how I can join the mappoints by mapline.

This is the final map with points selected by lines. http://jsfiddle.net/na85bqqp/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `mapline` in the series

```
 {
  type: 'mapline',
  name: 'Lines',
  color: 'green',
  data: [{
    name: 'line',
    path: 'M 5900 -7860 L 9230 -8090', /*first pair(5900 -7860) is point for Wisconsin and second(9230 -8090) is for London */
    lineWidth: 3
  }]
}
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/22wp7rwp/)

Comment: How did you find these numbers, 5900 and -7860? Can I work without **path** in data? I would ideally like mapline data to either work with lat/lon or name of the city, i.e Wisconsin and London. In my dataset, I don't have these numbers 5900 and -7860 and I don't want to run any javascript function for getting at these numbers, as I am serializing my data from python and using it with highcharts.

Comment: modifying this [highmap doc utility](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/adding-points-and-lines) -- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/chart/events-click-getcoordinates/) i am able to get  `y` and `x` value. you have to save this values to in db as you are saving `lat` and `lon` values